# Does a method to import/bulk import data into CRM 13 using the same CSV file but only adding new data exist?

Tags: excel, csv, import, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a situation where I have imported a bulk file of the Account and Contact records into CRM 13, and duplicate detection has kicked back a lot of the info for Contacts as failed because of duplicate data that ties back to the Account record.

Here are the steps I took:

- For my accounts record I removed dupes in Excel based off two fields, and it removed about 500 records from thousands.  I then imported the CSV file as is, into CRM 13
- Out of those 500, there could be unique records that I need to try and import into the CRM.
- I need to re-import the data into the CRM from an older file than the one I originally imported, and have the 500 records that were dropped added to the CRM.  But I don't have the time to dig through a few thousand rows of data and pick out each unique row of data and I don't want the CRM to re-add the entire Account record a second time to the system, giving me dupes in the CRM.
- Is there a way (without using a dynamic form, as they aren't working on the MS hosted CRMs, at the moment) to re-import the entire form, with the dropped unique records to the CRM and only add the unique data, and ignore the existing data?

I hope this makes sense.  I can try to clarify, if need be.  Thanks for any help you guys can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an export of the records from CRM, then use VLOOKUP in Excel to compare the difference in records, then import the difference to CRM again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the fact that whichever column you are using to match the account to the contact, there are multiple account records that match the criteria.

What I would suggest is ensuring that whatever you are using to identify account, that each value cannot resolve to more than one record. You could create a data map that resolves the account by something unique like account number.

Look at step #6 in the following example: https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/12/15/importing-lookup-values-using-crm-2011-data-import-wizard/

Comment: I did have dupe data.  I ended up having to go through it line by line using the highlight duplicate options in Excel, and peel that data out manually and add to a new form for a separate import..  Unfortunately, because it required two columns to be used as a check for duplicates, there really wasn't an easy method of doing it.  Thanks for the help, though, guys.